# Azure new Virtual Machine Windows Server 2022 can't make IIS work for a simple website

Tags: iis, azure, azure-networking, windows-server-2022

I got a new Azure Virtual machine server 2022 datacenter edition, they don't have the option "endpoints" where you configure the port 80 for http, I tried option "networking" 'add Inbound port rule' nada,
the issue is:  I can't see the website from outside.

then I went to 'connection troubleshoot' the result is 'network connectivity allowed' but the website still not working, I checked the IIS setup all seems fine.

seems like I'm missing something but I can't find it.

is there any step that I need to follow to allow IIS to work?

I went to azure support they want to charge me $XX.

I have a classic Azure virtual machine windows server 2012 that I run a very html simple website, I remembered to used the option "endpoints" where you configure the port 80 for http.

I will need to make a .Net core web API application to work, since the .Net API application doesn't work on Windows server 2012 r2.

Any help please will be appreciated!!

Comment: Do you have an NSG attached to the subnet or VM NIC? If so, do you have an inbound rule that allows port 80/443?

Comment: You should delete this server and create a new virtual machine. Make sure you add HTTP/HTTPS in "Inbound port rules" in the wizard of "Create a virtual machine".

Comment: "I will need to make a .Net core web API application to work, since the .Net API application doesn't work on Windows server 2012 r2" is a separate issue, so you should post a separate question and add more details on the error you met, not merely something not working.

Comment: thanks, the main issue is that a new clean Windows server 2022 doesn't work in handling a simple website, that means that port 80 is not forwarding to IIS.

Comment: How do you attach an NSG to the subnet what option? thanks

Comment: Is port 80 open? `Test-NetConnection -Port 80 -Computername ip' and when you run a `netstat -ano | findstr ":80" do you see port 80 listening? Is IIS running?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the connection:

```
$rgName = "ContosoRG"
$sourceVMName = "MultiTierApp0"
$destVMName = "Database0"

$RG = Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $rgName

$VM1 = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName | Where-Object -Property Name -EQ $sourceVMName
$VM2 = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName | Where-Object -Property Name -EQ $destVMName

$networkWatcher = Get-AzNetworkWatcher | Where-Object -Property Location -EQ -Value $VM1.Location 

Test-AzNetworkWatcherConnectivity -NetworkWatcher $networkWatcher -SourceId $VM1.Id -DestinationId $VM2.Id -DestinationPort 80
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-connectivity-powershell